# PHP subprocess from nodejs app doesn't output anything

Tags: php, node.js, typescript

I try to launch a PHP webserver from my nodejs application written in Typescript. The stdout/stderr of the PHP process must be redirected to a file in order to monitor it using another program.

I followed the documentation [here](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options), and wrote this code:

```
import * as child_process from "child_process";
import * as process from "process";
import * as fs from "fs";

let out = fs.openSync("./test.log", "a");
let err = fs.openSync("./test.log", "a");

let proc  = child_process.spawn("php -S 0.0.0.0:8080", {cwd: ".", env: process.env, shell: true, stdio: ["ignore", out, err]});
```

But the file test.log stays empty.

This code works when I execute a process that finishes (like **$ php -i**), but also with other long running processes like **$ ping**.

I also tried other solutions ...

```
let proc  = child_process.spawn("php", ["-S", "0.0.0.0:8080"], {cwd: ".", env: process.env, shell: false, stdio: ["ignore", out, err]});
```

```
let proc  = child_process.spawn("php", ["-S 0.0.0.0:8080"], {cwd: ".", env: process.env, shell: true, stdio: ["ignore", out, err]});
```

... but none of them worked.

What am I doing wrong ? Is it an issue with php or with my nodejs code ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import * as child_process from "child_process";
import * as process from "process";
import * as fs from "fs";

// let out = fs.openSync("./test.log", "a");
// let err = fs.openSync("./test.log", "a");

let proc  = child_process.spawn('php', ['-S', '0.0.0.0:8080']);

proc.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log('Failed to start child_process.', err);
});

proc.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  fs.writeFile('./test.log', data, function (err) {
     if (err) throw err;
  });
});

proc.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  fs.writeFile('./test.err', data, function (err) {
     if (err) throw err;
});
```

If you are still not getting output or are getting errors try changing the line to this:

```
let proc  = child_process.spawn('php' , ['-S', '127.0.0.1:8080']);
```

Comment: There are still no outputs from PHP. The file is not even created since proc.stdout.on is never called. It's weird, because when I run the command in a shell, it works correctly ...

Comment: @Tranqyll Is there 'Failed to start child_process.' in the console.log()? Perhaps the child process is not launching.

Comment: No there isn't. The process is launching, I can see it using my system monitor

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this?